# android Nfc not working in dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

i have a bottomSheetDialogFragment that allows user to scan a NFC tag but on some device when i put a tag near the phone nothing happens... (the phone does not vibrate or make any sound).

if i do the same things in an activity everything works as expected.

```
fun enableNFCInForeground(nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter, activity: Activity) {
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        activity, 0,
        Intent(activity, activity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0
    )
    val nfcIntentFilter = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
    val filters = arrayOf(nfcIntentFilter)

    val techLists = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(Ndef::class.java.name),
        arrayOf(NdefFormatable::class.java.name),
        arrayOf(MifareUltralight::class.java.name)
    )
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techLists)
}
```

The tag is a MiFareUltraLight.

Xiaomi Mi9 -> Ok
Samsung S20 FE -> KO

Comment: I'm not sure it could be done in a Dialog. "enableForegroundDispatch()" enables an Activity behaviour that will trigger (1) "Activity.onPause()", (2) "Activity.onResume()" and (3) "Activity.onNewIntent()" when an NFCTag is detected, but if the Dialog is opened I'm not sure it will work because the Activity has an opened Dialog....

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's optional for device manufacturers to implement the MifareUltralight Class

> Implementation of this class on a Android NFC device is optional. If it is not implemented, then MifareUltralight will never be enumerated in Tag#getTechList

From [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight)

The MifareUltralight Tag should still be able to be read by as a Type 2 (NfcA) Tag

So Try replacing

`arrayOf(MifareUltralight::class.java.name)`

with

`arrayOf(NfcA::class.java.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it wasn't a lifecycle or protocol problem.
In the same fragment im using a camera barcode reader and the NFC isn't working while camera is active

Comment: You might want to watch the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057353/accessing-camera-instance-using-camera-open-locks-nfc